# error while binding html with mysql database using django

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Insertemp.models import EmpInsert
from django.contrib import messages
#from django.http import HttpResponse
def Insertrecord(request):
   
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.POST.get('epname')and request.POST.get('email')and request.POST.get('country'):    
            saverecord=EmpInsert()
            saverecord.empname=request.POST.get('empname')
            saverecord.email=request.POST.get('email')
            saverecord.country=request.POST.get('country')
            saverecord.save()
            message.success(request,'Record Saved Successfully...!')
            
            return render(request,'Index.html')
    else:   
      
        return render(request,'Index.html')

     [views.py file][1]
```

when binding HTML form with MySQL database by django
after submiting submit button from html form I get error ValueError at /
The view Insertemp.views.Insertrecord didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not return anything if you are in a POST request but that one parameter is missing.

```
def Insertrecord(request):
   
    if request.method=='POST':

        if request.POST.get('epname')and request.POST.get('email')and request.POST.get('country'):    
            saverecord=EmpInsert()
            saverecord.empname=request.POST.get('empname')
            saverecord.email=request.POST.get('email')
            saverecord.country=request.POST.get('country')
            saverecord.save()
            message.success(request,'Record Saved Successfully...!')
            
            return render(request,'Index.html')

        else: # HERE IS THE MISSING ELSE
            return render(request,'Index.html') # OR RETURN SOMETHING ELSE

    else:   
      
        return render(request,'Index.html')

     [views.py file][1]
```

**Edit - About the message:**

You have to import messages: `from django.contrib import messages`

And you made a typo, writing `message` instead of `messages`.

Comment: so sir what should i change  in this code

Comment: @SIDDHANTMESHRAM Please read again the code that I posted, you will see the two lines that you have to add :)

Comment: i did the changes sir that u told me but still I am stuck

Comment: @SIDDHANTMESHRAM Can you please add the new exact content of your Insertrecord method in the bottom of your question ?

Comment: quest,'Record Saved Successfully...!')
            
            
        else: # HERE IS THE MISSING ELSE
            return render(request,'Index.html') 
            
           # return render(request,'Index.html')
        
    else:        
    
         return render(request,'Index.html')

Comment: sir after this above changes u told the page get refresh without any error but nothing happens

Comment: @SIDDHANTMESHRAM This is because at least one of your 3 parameters (epname, email or country) is missing, so no new record is created.

Comment: sir one of parameter is missing from code or HTML form from browser

Comment: yes sir now i got it actually at one part I had written epname instead of empname and therefore the error occurs , but now that earlier error is solved but sir now I have a new error Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value: 
name 'message' is not defined

Comment: @SIDDHANTMESHRAM I edited the end of my answer to answer you about that new error.

Comment: that error is solved sir thank you very much from bottom of my heart , u are great sir ,i pray u have a very happy and beutifull life.once again thank you soo much sir

Comment: @SIDDHANTMESHRAM I'm glad I could have helped! Could you please mark the question as answered by marking this answer as correct? You can have more explanations about that here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: sir after makingsome changes in this form i get the same error again i just added some drop down(option) and 3 text area input and geting the same value error please help me again sir please:

Comment: def Insertrecord(request):
 if request.method=='POST':
if request.POST.get('pname')and request.POST.get('pcategory')and request.POST.get('pdetails')and request.POST.get('foundedin')and request.POST.get('orderoftest')and request.POST.get('t1')and request.POST.get('t2')and request.POST.get('t3')and request.POST.get('f1')and request.POST.get('f2')and request.POST.get('f3')and request.POST.get('f4')and request.POST.get('f5'):    
 saverecord=EmpInsert()

Comment: saverecord.pname=request.POST.get('pname')
saverecord.pcategory=request.POST.get('pcategory')
saverecord.pdetails=request.POST.get('pdetails')
saverecord.foundedin=request.POST.get('foundedin')
saverecord.foundedin=request.POST.get('orderoftestimoni

Comment: al')saverecord.t1=request.POST.get('t1')saverecord.t2=request.POST.get('t2')
 saverecord.t3=request.POST.get('t3')
 saverecord.f1=request.POST.get('f1')
 saverecord.f2=request.POST.get('f2')
saverecord.f3=request.POST.get('f3') saverecord.f4=request.POST.get('f4' saverecord.f5=request.POST.get('f5')
saverecord.save() messages.success(request,'Record Saved Successfully...!')return render(request,'Index.html')
else: return render(request,'Index.html')

Comment: sir plz plz help me

Comment: @SIDDHANTMESHRAM Please open a new question with all the relevant code there, I can not help you more in the comments here.